# How to Convert â€™ to apostrophe(') in Perl

Tags: perl, special-characters

I am getting weird characters like ** â€™** and I need to convert it into apostrophe(') and other characters also . Please help on this. How can I decode or encode these charaters

Comment: What language are you using ?

Comment: you have probably encoding problems somewhere in your data transfer, try to use UTF-8 on every encoding/decoding

Comment: I am using perl. I have to import client database and add his posts to my forum and in their database it contains these types of special characters

Comment: You should read [perldoc perlunitut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlunitut.html) to learn how to process Unicode data in Perl.

Answer (score 0):

`â€™` is what the UTF-8 encoding of U+2019 RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK (’)<sup>[1]</sup> appears when viewed as Windows-1252.

Sounds like you should be encoding your output using Windows-1252 instead of UTF-8.

---

1. Not U+0027 APOSTROPHE (').